# How can I plot the gradient field in bipolar coordinates?

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

how I can plot the gradient of function V according to the attached program in bipolar coordinates.
I used from ParametricPlot to show bipolar coordinates as:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[Table[
    Tooltip[{Sinh[v]/(Cosh[v] - Cos[u]), Sin[u]/(Cosh[v] - Cos[u])}, 
     Row[{"u \[LongEqual] ", u}]], {u, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}]], {v, -1, 1}],
  ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[Table[
    Tooltip[{Sinh[v]/(Cosh[v] - Cos[u]), Sin[u]/(Cosh[v] - Cos[u])}, 
     Row[{"v \[LongEqual] ", v}]], {v, -1, 1, 1/10}]], {u, Pi/100, 
   2 Pi}]]
```

Now I want to calculate the gradient of the function V which is defined as:

```
NN = 150;
V0 = 5;
tau0 = 0.5;
V = V0*Sqrt [2*(Cosh [tau] - Cos [sigma])]*(
   LegendreQ[0 - 1/2, Cosh [tau0]]*LegendreP[0 - 1/2, Cosh [tau]]*
   Cos [0*sigma]/LegendreP[0 - 1/2, Cosh [tau0]] + 
    2*Sum[LegendreQ[n - 1/2, Cosh [tau0]]*LegendreP[n - 1/2, Cosh [tau]]*
     Cos [n*sigma]/LegendreP[n - 1/2, Cosh [tau0]], {n, 1, NN}])/Pi;
```

After taking the gradient I want to show the results in bipolar coordinate. The sample result is shown in the following.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Could you check your second definition (V)? It is not written properly.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is true. Anyway, I provide again it in the original form as a picture.

Comment: `LegendreQ[n/2,x]` is a complex number for `x>1`. I think `V` will also be a complex number. You can not plot complex number.

Comment: Thanks.
So can we use the Legendre function of the second kind of type 3 instead? Or select domain differently to have x<=1. Please consider any correct value to plot this function

Comment: To evaluate Q for x>1, we can use an optional argument to Mathematica's LegendreQ[] that puts the branch cut from −∞ to +1. This then makes Q real rather than complex for x>1.

Comment: For this stage, the important thing for me is about learning plot this function. So if there is a limitation about parameters or Legendre functions and so on, we can neglect them or change parameters to be in a correct domain solution.

Comment: @imankarimipour, if you are the same person as iman, I recommend that you use only one user name so that you can edit your own question without needing a review by others.

Answer (score 2):

### Prelude: bipolar coordinates

I use $(u, v)$ rather than $(\sigma, \tau)$ throughout. The [transformation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BipolarCoordinates.html) is given by$$\begin{align*}  x &= \frac{\sinh v}{\cosh v - \cos u} \\  y &= \frac{\sin u}{\cosh v - \cos u}.\end{align*}$$

Not so well known is the [inverse transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates#Reciprocal_relations) (which we will need for plotting):$$\begin{align*}  u &= \tan^{-1} \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2 - 1} \\  v &= \tanh^{-1} \frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}.\end{align*}$$

The scale factors (Lamé coefficients) for both coordinates are the same:$$  h_u = h_v = h = \frac{1}{\cosh v - \cos u}.$$

The local orthonormal basis is related to the standard Cartesian basis according to$$\begin{align*}  \mathbf{a}_u &= h (-S \,\mathbf{a}_x + C \,\mathbf{a}_y) \\  \mathbf{a}_v &= h (-C \,\mathbf{a}_x - S \,\mathbf{a}_y), \\\end{align*}$$
where
$$\begin{align*}  C &= \cos u \cosh v - 1 \\  S &= \sin u \sinh v.\end{align*}$$

Implementing this in Mathematica:

```
(* Coordinate transformations *)
xBipolar[u_, v_] := Sinh[v] / (Cosh[v] - Cos[u]);
yBipolar[u_, v_] := Sin[u] / (Cosh[v] - Cos[u]);

(* Inverse coordinate transformations *)
uBipolar[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x^2 + y^2 - 1, 2 y];
vBipolar[x_, y_] := ArcTanh[2 x / (x^2 + y^2 + 1)];
uvBipolar[x_, y_] := {uBipolar, vBipolar} @@ {x, y} // Through // Evaluate;

(* Scale factors (both are the same) *)
hBipolar[u_, v_] := 1 / (Cosh[v] - Cos[u]);

(* Abbreviations *)
cBipolar[u_, v_] := Cos[u] Cosh[v] - 1;
sBipolar[u_, v_] := Sin[u] Sinh[v];

(* Cartesian components of local orthonormal basis *)
uVectorBipolar[u_, v_] := hBipolar[u, v] {-sBipolar[u, v], cBipolar[u, v]} // Evaluate;
vVectorBipolar[u_, v_] := hBipolar[u, v] {-cBipolar[u, v], -sBipolar[u, v]} // Evaluate;
```

### Function

I have taken $v_0 = 1$. We have$$  \frac{V}{V_0} =  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty  \frac{1}{\pi}  \sqrt{2 (\cosh v - \cos u)}  \cdot  \lambda_n  \cdot  \frac{Q_{n-1/2}(\cosh v_0)}{P_{n-1/2}(\cosh v_0)}  \cdot  P_{n-1/2}(\cosh v)  \cos (n u).$$

```
(* lambda-bar *)
lambdaBar[0] = 1;
lambdaBar[n_] /; n > 0 = 2;

(* Expansion terms *)
v0 = 1;
term[n_][u_, v_] := (
  1 / Pi
  Sqrt[2 (Cosh[v] - Cos[u])]
  lambdaBar[n]
  LegendreQ[n - 1/2, Cosh[v0]] / LegendreP[n - 1/2, Cosh[v0]]
  LegendreP[n - 1/2, Cosh[v]]
  Cos[n u]
);

(* Partial sum for V/V_0 *)
partialSum[nMax_][u_, v_] := Sum[term[n][u, v], {n, 0, nMax}];
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `LegendreQ` factor isn't real, so we take the real part.

First we figure out how many terms we need to plot; I am guessing that the boundary condition which gives rise to the Fourier series is $V/V_0 = 1$ along the circle $v = v_0$:

```
nMaxValues = {0, 1, 2, 5};

Plot[
  Table[
    partialSum[nMax][u, v0] // Re
    , {nMax, nMaxValues}
  ] // Evaluate
  , {u, 0, 2 Pi}
  , PlotLegends -> LineLegend[nMaxValues, LegendLabel -> "nMax"]
]
```

[image: Fourier series for boundary condition]

**We see that 5 terms are enough.** We certainly don't need 150.

```
(* Assume function intended for v < v_0 only *)
regionFun = Function[{x, y}, Abs[vBipolar[x, y]] < v0];

(* Plot V/V_0 *)
Plot3D[
  partialSum[5] @@ uvBipolar[x, y] // Re // Evaluate
  , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
  , Exclusions -> None
  , RegionFunction -> regionFun
]
```

[image: Plot of function]

### Gradient

Next we take the gradient. Actually taking the derivative of a Fourier series is *non-trivial*. The $u$-derivative of $\cos(nu)$ introduces an extra factor of $n$, and if the coefficients do not go to zero fast enough, the term-by-term derivative will not converge. In this case though, the coefficients *do* go to zero fast enough for us to take a term-by-term derivative.

First define $\partial V / {\partial u}$ and $\partial V / {\partial v}$:

```
(* Derivatives of expansion terms *)
termUDerivative[n_][u_, v_] := D[term[n][u, v], u] // Evaluate;
termVDerivative[n_][u_, v_] := D[term[n][u, v], v] // Evaluate;

(* Derivatives partial sum *)
partialSumUDerivative[nMax_][u_, v_] := Sum[termUDerivative[n][u, v], {n, 0, nMax}];
partialSumVDerivative[nMax_][u_, v_] := Sum[termVDerivative[n][u, v], {n, 0, nMax}];
```

Since the scale factors for both coordinates are equal, the gradient is given by
$$  \nabla V =  \frac{1}{h}  \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial u} \,\mathbf{a}_u + \frac{\partial V}{\partial v} \,\mathbf{a}_v \right):$$

```
(* Partial sum for gradient of V/V_0 *)
gradientPartialSum[nMax_][u_, v_] :=
  1 / hBipolar[u, v] * Plus[
    partialSumUDerivative[nMax][u, v] uVectorBipolar[u, v],
    partialSumVDerivative[nMax][u, v] vVectorBipolar[u, v]
  ];
```

Finally we can plot the gradient (I chose `StreamPlot` because `VectorPlot` arrows are too small):

```
Show[
  ContourPlot[
    partialSum[5] @@ uvBipolar[x, y] // Re // Evaluate
    , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
    , AspectRatio -> Automatic
    , ContourShading -> None
    , Exclusions -> None
    , RegionFunction -> regionFun
  ],
  StreamPlot[
    gradientPartialSum[5] @@ uvBipolar[x, y] // Re // Evaluate
    , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
    , RegionFunction -> regionFun
  ]
]
```

[image: Plot of gradient]

Comment: Thanks so much.
If firstly we want to differentiate with respect to v from potential V  and then plot potential and gradient function is possible to do it? If so the common differentiate should be applied?

Comment: @iman I don't understand what you are asking. The StreamPlot is already a plot of the gradient.

Comment: Thanks. I have provided my question at the end of the body of the main primary question. Please see it and help again.

Comment: @iman That is not a Mathematica problem, but a PDE problem (which is off-topic for this site). Firstly you might need different eigenfunctions and eigenvalues to satisfy $\partial V/ {\partial v} = 0$ at $v = v_0$. Secondly this is an homogeneous boundary condition. You will need a separate inhomogeneous boundary condition to determine the coefficients of the Fourier series.

Comment: Dear friend.
I have been working on it, but I could not solve it. Could you please help me more in this regard? Thanks

Comment: My question is about the procedure for solving system of equations. I asked my question in the following post but I Haven’t receive any response .thank.   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230055/how-i-can-solve-an-infinite-system-of-equations/230120#230120